# Ansible Use First Defined Variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm in the process of updating a role that has to maintain backward compatibility.  It supports two versions of the program (v1 and v2) and uses different variables that mean the same thing, but the name is prepended with the version (i.e. `v1_my_val: True` and `v2_my_val: True`).

I am creating two seperate vars files (one for v1 and one for v2) that gets loaded based on which version is being used.  Common vars are put into each of the files (i.e. _my_val).  So here is the part that is messing me up.  I would like a single task that loads the first defined var in order if it is defined (i.e. v1_my_val, v2_my_val, _my_val).

Doing it with a single variable is easy enough (`my_val: {{ v1_my_val | default _my_val }}`) but not sure how to support the 2nd possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can get what you want using the [ternary filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ternary_filter.html)? Something like:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "first available value: {{ var1 is defined | ternary(var1, var2) | default('val3') }}"
```

If no variable is defined, running this produces:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
...
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "first available value: val3"
}
```

If `var1` is defined, we get the value of `var1` (even if `var2` is also defined):

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e var1=val1 -e var2=val2
...
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "first available value: val1"
}
```

If `var2` is defined (but not `var1`), we get the value of `var2`:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e var2=val2
...
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "first available value: val2"
}
```

Comment: I was looking at ternary but I couldn't figure out how to get to the third option....didn't dawn on me to add a default value also...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. For example:

- Put the variables into separate files

```yaml
shell> cat v1.yml 
my_val: v1

shell> cat v2.yml 
my_val: v2

shell> cat default.yml 
my_val: default
```

The below play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars_files:
    - "{{ my_version|d('default') }}.yml"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_val
```

gives, by default (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
  my_val: default
```

If you provide the play with the variable `my_version=v2` the play gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e my_version=v2
  ...
  my_val: v2
```